# Software caused connection abort: socket write error while writing to DataOutputStream

Tags: java

```
 private DataOutputStream output = null;
 private int send(String str) throws IOException {
  int response = 0;
  output.writeBytes(str);
  output.flush();
  return response;
```

}

While writing String to writeBytes it is throwing error like 
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 512

DEBUG McaFee:123 - Exception  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
McaFeeC:83 - Request Header **** GET http://localhost:8080/appApp\filepath\ACH_IMAGE_FIVE_TWO_FIVE_zip HTTP/1.1

Comment: we can't see the initialization of "output", but beware of writeBytes(string), terrible method

Comment: Can you provide us with the complete stack trace of the Exception and the code where the error is thrown?

Comment: `DataOutputStream` is not initialized here. Can you also paste wole stack trace of the Exception?

Comment: DEBUG McaFee:123 - Exception java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error McaFeeC:83 - Request Header **** GET http://localhost:8080/appApp\filepath\ACH_IMAGE_FIVE_TWO_FIVE_zip HTTP/1.1

Comment: Actually I am uploading 600 images in zip file then it is throwing exception. If I upload 500 images in zip file it is not throwing any exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your question misses the part how you initialize the `DataOutputStream` but the error message lets me assume that you open an `HttpUrlConnection` to a server and call `getOutputStream` on it.

Your question also misses the part where you create the `String` that is passed to the `send` method and if you indeed create a ZIP-file using a `String` to contain that binary data will most likely lead to corrupted data at some point.

My answer is based on the following code I assume is working here:

```
HttpUrlConnection conn = new URL("www.example.com/upload").openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
String dataToSend = createDataToSend();
dos.writeBytes(dataToSend.getBytes("8859_1"));
```

What can happen here is that the `HttpUrlConnection` is opening the connection to the server and then the connections sits idle until you've finished creating the ZIP. If it takes too long the server will run into a timeout and will close the connection. Trying to send data to a closed socket lead to the error message you've seen.

The reason why it works up to a given number of files is that the generation is then quick enough to stay within the timeout.

There are different solutions for this:

- Create the ZIP before you open the connection
- Create the ZIP "on the fiy" by sending the data during creation

Which one is better depends. If you can be sure that there will be no error
while creating the ZIP it would be my preferred way. The former would prevent
the sending of incomplete data in case of an error. Note that the latter
needs Chunked File-Transfer-Encoding, otherwise the `HttpUrlConnection`
will buffer everything to evaluate the value for the `Content-Length` header
that would otherwise be needed. So if you transfer data to a server that
is not supporting this, you end up with variant 1.

Here is an example for the latter:

```
private int doSend(File baseDir) throws IOException {
    File[] files = baseDir.listFiles();
    if (files.length == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("www.example.com/upload").openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(250);
    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(os);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(files[i].getName());
        zos.putNextEntry(ze);
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files[i])) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            int read;
            while ((read = fis.read(buf)) != -1) {
                zos.write(buf, 0, read);
            }
        }
    }
    zos.flush();
    return conn.getResponseCode();
}
```